# Google Chrome on Ubuntu 21.10: web pages are blank

Tags: google-chrome, 21.10

I'm running latest google-chrome-stable on Ubuntu 21.10.
When I open Chrome, it goes to the start page, where there are icons for links to several different pages.  Everything looks fine.  As soon as I go to a specific page, doesn't matter if I click an icon in start page or enter a URL, the screen goes blank, and then it just sits there, spinning.  This happens for all pages.  I have no idea what's going on.  If I go to chrome://settings, that page is displayed correctly.  But it says sync is paused.  If I try to login again to unpause it, it opens another tab, and spins forever, again.  Help!

I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on 21.10. Network issue? Does Firefox work normally?

Comment: Ok, making (some) progress.  Firefox is fine, and Chrome is fine in incognito mode, so, no, not a network problem, I don't thinl.  This is *really* weird.

Comment: Rename the Chrome profile folder so it is out of the way: that will start Chrome with factory default settings. If you want to revert, delete the newly created profile folder and move the old one back in place.

Comment: Ok, I'll tru that now.

Comment: That did it, I'm all good!  Thanks!  If you enter as an answer, I'll upvote and accept.